# iOS - How to update information in specific cell of a table (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**UPDATE**

Alright, so I pull information from a mysql database and then display it in a table, where each cell contains information for a specific ticket corresponding to information in the mysql database.

However, in another function I update the the information for a certain ticket (in the database) and want to update the cells holding the information of the ticket accordingly.

The main issue is that I'm unable to call each cell on its own so I can just update the information in the cell without having to update (reloading) all cells.

So say I update the information for ticket #2. I want a way I can call cell #2 and update the information just for that cell.

---

So, I'm currently creating my cells like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int count = 0;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

      cell *cell1 = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    if(cell1 == nil){
        cell1 = [[cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    HelpDeskCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...

    items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cleanliness", @"Door", @"Peek Hole", @"Sink", @"Towel Rack", @"Closet", @"Carpet", @"Wall", @"Bed", @"Matress", @"Mattress Cover", @"Fridge", @"Blinds", @"Window", @"Screen", @"Air Conditioning", @"Chair", @"Desk", @"Garbage bin", @"Shelves", @"Phone", @"Jacks", @"Lights", @"Smoke Detector", @"Heat Detector", @"Light bulb", @"Deep Cleaning", @"Final Prep", nil];



    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        count = 1;
        // first row
        NSString *title;

        if (self.filterClass.orderedBy == 1) {
             title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %d   (%d)", indexPath.section + 1 ,myArray[indexPath.section]];
        }
        else {
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)", items[indexPath.section],myArray[indexPath.section]];
        }

        [cell1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
        [cell1.titleLabel setText:title];

        if (myArray[indexPath.section] > 0) {
            [cell1.canOpen setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
            [cell1.canOpen setText:@">"];
        }
        else {
            [cell1.canOpen setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
            [cell1.canOpen setText:@""];
        }

        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        int row = indexPath.row - 1;
        int section = indexPath.section;
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[HelpDeskCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        CGFloat fontsize = 16;

        if([[[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]
             objectForKey:@"priority"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"]){

            [cell.IDLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else{
            [cell.IDLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.925 green:0.925 blue:0.925 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        [cell.IDLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];



        //reduce fontsize to 12 for the information labels
        //same on all devices and orientations
        fontsize = 12;

        //ticket status label
        [cell.statusLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.statusLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        //ticket category label
        [cell.categoryLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [cell.categoryLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.categoryLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        //ticket title label
        [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //Label holds the user that submitted the ticket
        [cell.submittedLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.submittedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //Label holds the user currently working on the ticket
        [cell.handleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.handleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //ticket date label
        [cell.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];



        // Set the text of the subviews
        NSString * ticketIdStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"ticket_id"];
        [cell.IDLabel setText:ticketIdStr];
        NSString * ticketStatusStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"status"];
        [cell.statusLabel setText:ticketStatusStr];
        if([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.6 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"In Progress"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.733 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Resolved"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Closed"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        NSString * categoryStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"category"];
        [cell.categoryLabel setText:categoryStr];
        NSString * titleStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * userIDStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"user_id"];
        NSString * handledByStr = [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"handled_by"];
        [cell.titleLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@", titleStr]];
        [cell.submittedLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Submitted By: %@", userIDStr]];
        [cell.handleLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handled By: %@", handledByStr]];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *orignalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"date_submitted"] substringToIndex:10]];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
        NSString * ticketDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:orignalDate];

        [cell.dateLabel setText:ticketDateStr];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    if (count == 1) {
        return cell1;
    }

    return cell;
        }
```

I load a nib for each cell then update the information there. Example:

```
 [cell.statusLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.statusLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

However I'm having difficulty calling each cell and then updating it from another function it. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain bit more?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Not related but calling `[[multiArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row]` 8 times to get always the same object is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Working on someone else's project, ill fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need it to call

```
HelpDeskCell *cell = (HelpDeskCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:#someIndexPath#];
```

in your other function. Assuming you know which ticket/cell you want to update and then call

```
cell.statusLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

or any other update you want to make